# java реализация функции возврата строки в строке только методом length

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, строки, char

Здравствуйте! Недавно получил задание: 
Написать реализацию функции:
Int pos(String search, String where);
Где:
search - искомая строка, where - где ищем.
Функция возвращает позицию строки search в строке where или -1, если вхождение не найдено. Строку считать массивом Char(индексация от 0). Char между собой можно сравнивать. У строки есть только метод length(), других методов нет.

Прошу помощи у более опытных. Решил сперва с помощью indexOf(), но естественно ответ не был засчитан.
Также думал, что нужно сравнить длину строки search с длинами элементов массива where, но вот как это вылить в синтаксис java не приходит в голову.

Не обязательно писать весь код, можно привести аналогию, направить по ссылкам к похожим задачам.

Спасибо!

Comment: А почему просто поэлементо не сравнить?

Comment: скорее всего предполагается использование charAt

Comment: нет,  без charAt'а

Comment: вы вхождение с одним length() не найдете, да и зачем в задании были бы фразы "Строку считать массивом Char(индексация от 0)"?

Comment: а также ,цитирую "У строки есть только метод length(), других методов нет." Изменять условия задачи не могу, как бы не хотелось. Это один из первых методов, который мне выдал гугл, в т.ч. и indexOf(), который был отклонен.

Comment: а еще есть "Char между собой можно сравнивать." indexOf был отклонён т.к. вам по сути и надо его реализовать.

Comment: Может быть от вас хотят чтобы вы реализовали алгоритм Кнута — Морриса — Пратта ?

https://habrahabr.ru/post/191454/

Comment: Спасибо! возможно этот метод я смогу понять и использовать в будущем, но вряд ли на данный момент от новичка(1,5мес джавы на codecademy и 10уровней джавараша) потребуют столь "изощренного" метода решения данной задачи. //На wikibooks есть пример для джавы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишу вариант со сравнением посимвольно, т.к. в задании скорее всего опечатка и только с одним length() его сделать невозможно.

```
public static int pos(String search, String where) {
    //искомая строка должна быть не больше той, в которой ищем
    if (search.length() > where.length()) {
        return -1;
    }
    //ищем только до определенной позиции, т.к. дальше искомая строка уже не "влезет"
    for (int i = 0; i < where.length() - search.length() + 1; i++) {
        // если совпадает первый символ ...
        if (where.charAt(i) == search.charAt(0)) {
            boolean found = true;
            // ... то сверим все остальные
            for (int j = i + 1; j < i + search.length(); j++) {
                // если хоть один не совпадает ...
                if (where.charAt(j) != search.charAt(j - i)) {
                    // ... значит не нашли
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // если все символы совпали
            if (found) {
                //значит нашли и возвращаем позицию
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    //ничего не нашли
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое! не будет ли наглостью если попрошу вас добавить комментарии?

Comment: Вы были правы, задача составлена не корректно!

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм  Кнута — Морриса — Пратта,  взят отсюда   [алгоритм](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0)

```
public static int[] indexesOf(char[] pattern, char[] text) {
        int[] pfl = pfl(pattern);
        int[] indexes = new int[text.length];
        int size = 0;
        int k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
            while(pattern[k] != text[i] && k > 0) {
                k = pfl[k - 1];
            }
            if(pattern[k] == text[i]) {
                k = k + 1;
                if(k == pattern.length) {
                    indexes[size] = i + 1 - k;
                    size += 1;
                    k = pfl[k - 1];
                }
            } else {
                k = 0;
            }
        }
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(indexes, 0, size);
    }

    public static int[] pfl(char[] text) {
        int[] pfl = new int[text.length];
        pfl[0] = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < text.length; ++i) {
            int k = pfl[i - 1];
            while(text[k] != text[i] && k > 0) {
                k = pfl[k - 1];
            }
            if(text[k] == text[i]) {
                pfl[i] = k + 1;
            } else {
                pfl[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        return pfl;
    }
```

как использовать

```
     String s2 = "ее";
     String s1 = "ццццццццццццццееццццуувыфывфыв";

        int[] answer = indexesOf(s2.toCharArray() , s1.toCharArray());


        for(int q : answer) {
            System.out.println(q);  //  14
        }
```

Массив содержит все позиции схожих подстрок, но она одна и равна  14

Comment: Благодарю! Возможно данный метод и является решением, но для моего понимания он на данный момент сложен, словно решение квадратного уравнения с отрицательным корнем с помощью комплексных чисел для ученика 8-го класса.

Answer (score 0):

поиск делаешь в цикле от нуля до длины where - длина search
делаешь substring из where длиной search и сравниваешь с search
и так итерация по шагово со сдвигом на один символ
функцию substring если использовать внешнею нельзя то достаточно легко самому написать :)

```
for (int i=0; i < where.length() - search.length(); i++){ 
  if (substring(search, i, where.length()) == search) { 
    return i; 
  }
}
```

Comment: не совсем понял, что вы написали.  for(int i=0; i<where.length(); i++){
            search.length() = where.substring(search.length(i));
        }     ?

Comment: for (int i=0; i < where.length() - search.length(); i++){ if (substring(search, i, where.length()) == search) { return i; }}

Comment: Если substring можно использовать то соотвественно where.substr(i, search.length());

Comment: строка, а именно логическое выражение if (substring(search, i, where.length()) == search) мне непонятна, т.к. еще до этого раздела джавы я еще видимо не дошел. Напишите пожалуйста,что за тема.