# Проверить что одна строка является подстрокой другой, не используя String.contains

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, строки, split

Создать программу проверяющую, что строка `ens` является подстрокой `obsensevity`.

```
boolean contains(String origin, String sub).
```

Нельзя использовать `String.indexOf`, `String.contains`. 
Нужно преобразовать строку в массив символов и проверить.

Вот такое у меня задание если кто-то сможет помочь буду очень признателен.
Если можно с расщеплением при помощи `split("")`.

```
public boolean contains(String origin, String sub) {
    String[] arrOrigin = origin.split("");
    String[] arrSub = origin.split("");
    int equals = 0;
    boolean result = false;
    if (arrOrigin.length >= arrSub.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrSub.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrOrigin.length; j++) {
                if (arrOrigin[j].equals(arrSub[i])) {
                    equals++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (equals == arrSub.length) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: А просто `"obsensevity".contains("sen");` не?

Comment: К сожалению String.contains запрещена. Это все-таки учебное задание. Надо сделать как педагог сказал.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556097/java-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот еще вариант с использованием `split`:

```
  class MyTest {

  // Проверить, содержится ли pattern в examinee
  private static boolean contains(String examinee, String pattern) {
    if (pattern.length() > examinee.length()) return false; 
    String s1 = " " + examinee + " ";    // гарантируем непустую строку слева и справа
    String s2 = "\\Q" + pattern + "\\E"; // Трактовать как литерал
    if(s1.split(s2).length > 1) return true; // что-то есть и слева, и справа
    return false;
  };

  // A Q&D test data set
  static String[][] testData = {
      {"qwerty", "wer"},  
      {"qwerty", "qwerty"},  
      {" qwerty", "qwerty"},  
      {"qwerty ", "qwerty"},  
      {"qwerty", " qwerty "},  
      {"по реке", "плывет"},  
      {"по реке", ".*"},  
      {"по реке", " "},  
  };

  // Tests all the above data and shows the results
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String[] pair: testData) 
      System.out.printf("'%s' contains '%s': %s\n", 
                        pair[0], pair[1], contains(pair[0], pair[1]));
  }

}
```

Выводит:

```
'qwerty' contains 'wer': true
'qwerty' contains 'qwerty': true
' qwerty' contains 'qwerty': true
'qwerty ' contains 'qwerty': true
'qwerty' contains ' qwerty ': false
'по реке' contains 'плывет': false
'по реке' contains '.*': false
'по реке' contains ' ': true
```

Comment: О как интересно значит split  может принимать аргументы

Comment: if(s1.split(s2).length > 1) return true А что происходит в методе сплит если туда строку послать?

Comment: @Павел, `split` принимает в качестве аргумента строку, которую интерпретирует как регулярное выражение, и разделяет исходную строку на подстроки в тех местах, где это регулярное выражение совпадает: new String("куку123реку321руку").split("\\d+") даст {"куку","реку","руку"}. См. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Comment: А да понял прикольная штука и решение короткое что всегда приятно. Только оно не сработает в случае если подстрока будет в конце или в начале оригинальной строки. Получившийся массив тоже будет иметь length = 1.

Comment: @Павел, ну как это не сработает - вот же строки в тестовых данных: `{" qwerty", "qwerty"},  
      {"qwerty ", "qwerty"}`, и вывод на консоль приведен. Скопируйте себе всю программу целиком, подставьте любые тестовые данные и прогоните, проверьте.

Comment: А да точно не заметил этого. Хотел просто подстроку в сплит послать)))

Comment: @Павел Да. Там, кстати, первый пробел в `String s1 = " " + examinee + " ";`  на самом деле не нужен, достаточно `String s1 = examinee + " ";`

Comment: На самом деле крутой вариант, люблю когда просто. Интересно мой препод завернет меня с такой инициативой...)))

Comment: Плюс за юнит-тесты!

Answer (score 5):

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    static boolean contains(String origin, String sub)
    {
        String[] originArray = origin.split( "" );
        String[] subArray    = sub.split( "" );

        int originLength = originArray.length;
        int subLength    = subArray.length;

        boolean found = false;

        if ( subLength <= originLength )
        {
            for ( int i = 0; !found && i < originLength - subLength + 1; i++ )
            {
                int j = 0;

                while ( j < subLength && originArray[i + j].equals( subArray[j] ) ) j++; 

                found = j == subLength;
            }
        }

        return found;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String origin = "obsensevity";
        String sub = "ens";

        System.out.println( "\"" + origin + "\" contains \"" + sub + "\" is " +
                            contains( origin, sub ) );
    }
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
"obsensevity" contains "ens" is true
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы объяснить вот это место, извините если глупый вопрос.

Comment: while ( j < subLength && originArray[i + j].equals( subArray[j] ) ) j++; 

                found = j == subLength;

Comment: В особенности originArray[i + j].equals( subArray[j]

Comment: и вот это   found = j == subLength

Comment: Это что получается он сначала сравнивается j == subLength а потом присваивается found = или наоборот?

Comment: А извиняюсь затупил с found = (j == subLength) обычно скобочки себе ставлю для читабельности но вот с сигнатурой цикла while все таки мне не понятно что за идея? а если бы буквы ens были в NobSsevityE программа бы их тоже засчитала?

Comment: Ну тоесть если бы символы из которых состоит sub  шли разбросанные по origin то программа выведет true по идее задания не должна

Comment: @Павел В этом цикле while ( j < subLength && originArray[i + j].equals( subArray[j] ) ) j++;  идет проход по массиву subarray и каждый его элемент сравнивается с соответствующим элементом в originArray, начиная с позиции i. Если все элементы равны между собой, то j будет равен после цикла subLength.

Comment: @Павел Имейте в виду, что регистр символов важен. В противном случае символы всех строк обоих массивов надо приводить к одному регистру: либо к верхнему, либо к нижнему. То есть текущая функция ищет точное совпадение.

Comment: Да да про регистр я понял спасибо. А вот с циклами все равно не пойму((( а for что делает? извините что мучаю, может я как-то думаю не правильно не знаете может есть какая-то типичная методология работы с циклами. А то куча инкрементов туда сюда пока одно прибавил другое забыл, ну вы понимаете... Как вы это изначально планируете?

Comment: @Павел Вы должны проверить, что каждый элемент subArray равен соответствующему элементу originArray, которые внутри originArray начинаются с некоторой позиции. В данном случае i. Поэтому j изменяется от 0 до subLength и при этом каждый элемент subarray[j] должен быть равен элементу originArray[I+j]. Либо цикл завершается, когда все элементы равны, либо когда встретились неравные элементы. Если все элементы равны, то после выхода из цикла j будет равно subLength.

Comment: А возможно разбить эти циклы на несколько более простых для наглядности? Или ерунда получится? Как говориться сложное это сложенное из простых.

Comment: @Павел Что разбивать? И так все просто. В цикле while каждый элемент массива  subArray сравнивается последовательно с элементами массива  originArray, начиная с его некоторой позиции I. Куда уж проще?

Comment: А в чем ошибка в этом решении?

Comment: Ниже сам решил но не правильно(((

Comment: @Павел  Что вы мучаетесь? Я предоставил корректное и простое решение.

Comment: Мне надо понять и самому решить я же учусь. Смысл сдавать задание сделанное не мной если я не могу это повторить сам? Воспаление хитрости было бы хорошо если бы финансовый поток шел в противоположенном направлении. А так получится куплю билет и пойду пешком.

Comment: @Павел Так что непонятного-то? Элементы массива subarray имеют индекмы в диапазлне [0, subLength). Вот переменная j и проходит по этим индексам сравнивая соответствующие элементы в subarray с элементами originArray. Только у originArray начало, с которого происходит сравнение постоянно сдвигается вправо в соответствии с заданным индексом i. То есть в originArray вы должны сравнивать элементы с subArray , начиная с индекса I, то есть в диапазоне [I+0, I + subLength)

Answer (score 2):

Вот сделал решение сам, на основе ваших подсказок. Всем большое спасибо! Особенно Vlad from Moscow за терпение.

```
    public boolean contain(String origin, String sub) {
    if (origin.length() < sub.length()) { return false; }
    char[] arrOrigin = origin.toCharArray();
    char[] arrSub = sub.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <= arrOrigin.length - arrSub.length; i++) {
        if (arrSub[0] == arrOrigin[i]) {
            char[] forEqual = new char[arrSub.length];
            System.arraycopy(arrOrigin, i, forEqual, 0,arrSub.length);
            if (Arrays.equals(forEqual, arrSub)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Осталось написать пачку юнит-тестов с кейсами, включающими разный регистр, юникод и т.п. )

Comment: Это будет работать, но я бы на вашем месте посмотрел ещё раз решения остальных участников (например Влада), вы постоянно перевыделяете память и делаете копирование,  это не очень хорошо с точки зрения производительности.

Comment: pavel прав. И еще `if (arrOrigin.length < arrSub.length) { return false; }` лучше поставить в самом начале - если длина образца превышает длину исходной строки, то строить массивы символов arrOrigin, arrSub нет никакой нужды - это будет пустая трата процессорного времени. И переменная result нигде не изменяется - лучше ее не описывать, а в конце использовать константу: `return false` - код будет проще и яснее

Comment: Юнит тесты я сделал просто не выложил не хотел загромождать пространство. Да по поводу того что pavel сказал это да, действительно прав на 100%, подумаю постараюсь поправить. Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: У Влада лучшее решение, по производительности это точно! Но, я пока не как не могу допереть в эти циклы(((. Наверно я не много перегрелся надо отвлечься и потом еще раз посмотреть что он там делает. Он мне даже объяснить пытался, но как говориться умные мысли меня преследуют но я быстрее...)))

Answer (score 1):

О, я не заметил вначале, что нужно использовать массивы символов. Тогда вот так:
  `static private boolean contains2(String examinee, String pattern) {
    if (pattern.length() > examinee.length()) return false; 
    char[] origAry = examinee.toCharArray();
    char[] ptrnAry = pattern.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <= (origAry.length - ptrnAry.length); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < ptrnAry.length; j++) {
        if (origAry[i + j] != ptrnAry[j]) break;
        if (j == ptrnAry.length - 1) return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };`

Но как сюда приплести `split`, я не могу придумать.